# NSubstitute and DbContext.Set<TEntity> Could not find a call to return from

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dbcontext, nsubstitute

I am trying to write some tests for an existing service we have. It uses the **DbContext** (In our case, named DatabaseContext) and the constructor looks like this:

```
public GenericOrderProvider(DatabaseContext context, IOrderHandler<T> orderHandler)
{
    _orderHandler = orderHandler;
    _context = context;
    _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
}
```

As you can see, it's generic and sets the `_dbSet` when it's initialized.
I have this very simple method:

```
public Attempt<IQueryable<T>> List(params string[] includes)
{
    var x = _dbSet.ToList();

    return Attempt<IQueryable<T>>.Succeed(_dbSet.OrderBy(m => m.Order));
}
```

And I wrote this test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ListShould
{
    [Test]
    public void ReturnList()
    {
        // Assemble
        var services = GenericOrderProviderContext.GivenServices();
        var provider = services.WhenCreateOrderProvider();

        services.DatabaseContext.Set<Attribute>().ReturnsForAnyArgs(new List<Attribute>().ToDbSet());
        //services.DatabaseContext.Attributes = new List<Attribute>().ToDbSet();

        // Act
        var result = provider.List();

        // Assert
        result.Failure.Should().BeFalse();
        result.Result.Count().Should().Be(0);
    }
}
```

When I run that test, I get the error:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException : Could not find a call to return from.

The trace specifically targets the line `services.DatabaseContext.Set<Attribute>().ReturnsForAnyArgs(new List<Attribute>().ToDbSet());` but I have no idea how to fix it.
As far as I can tell, I am mapping to the right method.

For completeness, here is my test **Contexts**:

```
public class GenericOrderProviderContext: DatabaseContextContext<GenericOrderProviderContext>
{
    public static GenericOrderProviderContext GivenServices() => new GenericOrderProviderContext();

    public IGenericOrderProvider<Attribute> WhenCreateOrderProvider() =>
        new GenericOrderProvider<Attribute>(DatabaseContext,
            new OrderHandler<Attribute>(DatabaseContext));

    public bool IsSequential(List<Attribute> models)
    {
        return !models.OrderBy(m => m.Order).Select(m => m.Order).Select((i, j) => i - j).Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
    }
}

public class DatabaseContextContext<T> where T: DatabaseContextContext<T>
{
    public DatabaseContext DatabaseContext;
    protected DatabaseContextContext()
    {
        DatabaseContext = Substitute.For<DatabaseContext>();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: It seems like there might be non-virtual calls causing a problem here. Can you add [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) package and see if that detects any problems?

Comment: I have added the package. the error I get now is `System.NotImplementedException : The method or operation is not implemented.`